# Reaching those punctuation keys on a QWERTY keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, typing

Do you type properly using all your fingers on all the right keys?  I find accessing common punctuation on a standard QWERTY layout to be very frustrating when coding.  Brackets, square brackets, angled brackets, quotes, etc. are used so much, yet I always miss the keys since they are sometimes a stretch.  I know there are alternate keyboard layouts (DVORAK, etc.) but I don't know if I am willing to completely relearn a less common keyboard layout.  Are you fast and accurate with your punctuation keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a matter of getting used to it.  Assuming you can touch-type, it's just practice.  Also, make sure your keyboard is always the same, both home and at work, so your fingers never get confused.

If you cannot touch type, I'd recommend you tackle that first, since it's extremely helpful when you have to type all day long as your day job.

Comment: Cool. Yes I can touch-type letters at 70 wpm, but with regular punctuation while programming I often lose my home row or miss keys.  Just need more practice I guess, thanks.